# Does anyone know why Visual Studio can't set a breakpoint after the update？

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, razor

I upgraded the version from 2019 to 2022；
[image]

But this action caused a problem: I cannot insert breakpoint anymore (.cshtml file)，other formats can still insert breakpoints.
[image]

[image]

I tried to modify the debug settings, failed.
I don't know the reason, so can anyone tell me the reason?
I am sure the code has no problem, is it the reason for the version 2022?

Comment: I don't know why you are being downvoted, but this is a legit issue in VS 2022 - breakpoints can't be set in Razor files and intellisense seems to be broken - you can't navigate to class definitions from Razor files.

Comment: I don't know why I am being downvoted too...Maybe this problem doesn't have much value?But for me, this is the problem.Now I am using VS2019，breakpoint can be set in Razor files in VS2019，if this is indeed a legit issue in VS2022...I just wanna know Will this problem be solved with the version update?Or always?

Comment: This issue has been raised in the [community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-Add-Breakpoint-to-Razor-File/1532940?space=8&q=%5BVisual+Studio+2022+version+17.0%5Drazor), and you can continue to follow up in the community.

Comment: Same bug with latest **Visual Studio 2022 17.0.2** (**Visual Studio 2019 16.11** works correctly). I've created a [new issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-place-breakpoint-in-asp-core-60-razor-pa-2/1608057).

Comment: If this is the same issue, it looks to be in a "Fixed pending release" status as of Dec 13, 2021, here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-place-breakpoint-in-viewcshtml/1501243

Comment: Facing the same issue. It was working in VS 2022 (17.0.5) but as I uninstall the older version(VS 2019).

Comment: best I can tell it is being ignored as a problem in the communtity.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:
Instead of inline code like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.template.Css)
```

Try to refactor like this:

```
@{
    Html.Raw(Model.projectCss);
}
```

You can then place the breakpoint on the line in the middle.